# mySQL query with count / grouping

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having the following data:

```
ID   user    value     lang
------------------------------
1    1       foo1      de
2    1       foo2      de
3    1       bar1      en
4    1       bar2      en
5    1       bar3      en
6    1       bar4      fr
```

desired output:

```
user   de    en    fr 
------------------------------
1      2     3     1
```

i want to get the total count of all languages from user 1.

I've tried with `COUNT`, `SUM` and `HAVING` .. but it didn't work.

Comment: Can you please add what you have tried? Did you `group by`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use conditional aggregation

```
SELECT user,
       SUM(CASE WHEN lang='de' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'de',
       SUM(CASE WHEN lang='en' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'en',
       SUM(CASE WHEN lang='fr' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'fr'
  FROM t
 GROUP BY user
```

or directly without conditionals :

```
SELECT user,
       SUM(lang='de') as 'de',
       SUM(lang='en') as 'en',
       SUM(lang='fr') as 'fr'
  FROM t
 GROUP BY user
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ea1707f32d3cc64edf223d9aea05e213)</kbd>